# Change the size of "all" seaborn plots in the python code

Tags: python, plot, size, seaborn

I am trying to determine the size of ALL the figures produced by seaborn in my code (one kdeplot, and one jointplot).

The code is:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
sns.kdeplot(DF["x"], DF["y"], cmap="viridis")
plt.show()

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
sns.jointplot(DF["x"], DF["y"], color ="blue")
plt.show()
```

With this code, only the size of the first figure (kde) is changed, and the second one is still small.
However, if the second plot is a **kdeplot** as well, then the size is adjusted well!
If both are jointplot, none of them change the size!
What is the solution? Why size of the jointplot does not change!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try asigning the jointplot and then set the figure size:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

x = np.arange(10)
y = x * 2

DF = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y})

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
sns.kdeplot(DF["x"], DF["y"], cmap="viridis")

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
myplot = sns.jointplot(DF["x"], DF["y"], color ="blue")
myplot.fig.set_size_inches(10,10)
```